# React Native : [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, expo

I'm making a simple weather report app with React, Expo. But, there are axios error. Here are my code.
I've cchecked related post on stackkoverflow, but thosee didn't work .

[React Native unhandled promise rejection network error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62737791/react-native-unhandled-promise-rejection-network-error)

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed expo node backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031415/unhandled-promise-rejection-typeerror-network-request-failed-expo-node-backend)

```
export default class extends React.Component{

    state={
        isLoading : true,
    }
    getWeather = async(latitude,longitude) => {
        const url = `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`;
        const {data: {
            main :{ temp },weather}} = await axios.get(url);
        this.setState({
            isLoading:false,
            temp: data.main.temp,
            condition:weather[0].main,});
    }
    getLocation = async() => {
      try {
          await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
          const {coords : {latitude, longitude}} = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();
          this.getWeather(latitude,longitude);
        } 
        catch (error)
        {
          Alert.alert("Can't find you.", "So sad");

      }
      
  }
  componentDidMount(){
      this.getLocation();
  }
  render(){
      const {isLoading, temp, condition} = this.state;
      return isLoading ? <Loading /> : <Weather temp={Math.round(temp)} condition={condition} />
  }
}
```

I've checked  whether the url has the problem ,  but it worked fine. The problem was on axios

Here are error messages.

```
Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error]
```

at node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:14:6 in settle
at node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:65:6 in handleLoad
at node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:600:10 in setReadyState
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

the address that I used is "exp://172.16.218.87:19000"

here is my package.json file.

```
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Thanks!!